# How to set pie chart series data from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, pie-chart

I am using a epiechart js from Gentellela Alela, but I want to generate a dynamic chart with the data I got from mysql, I then made a query on php then i passed the data to javascript. I am so close but was tired searching after for hours. I want to insert values from my variable countData and names from genData. This is the default series:

```
series: [{
      name: '访问来源',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '55%',
      center: ['50%', '48%'],
      data: [{
        value: 335,
        name: 'Direct Access'
      }, {
        value: 310,
        name: 'E-mail Marketing'
      }]
```

I tried to set it like this, values are loaded properly but the names are not loaded:

```
series: [{
      name: 'Genres in use',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '55%',
      center: ['50%', '48%'],
      data: countData,genData
    }]
```

I've tried looping, changing how i set the data and a bunch of other stuff which didnt work but I am really unfamiliar to javascript syntax and functions. I failed to figure out how to make this work so I'm asking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my close friend, I found out the solution was so simple. :)
Using a looped array push, I was able to make an array that is of the same format that the script was expecting

```
<script>

  var series = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < countData.length; i++)
  {
    var item = { value: countData[i], name: genData[i] };
    series.push(item);
  }

</script>
```